# .Net regex to look for a credit card number in a string

Tags: c#, regex

does anyone know in C# how to look for a credit card number inside a string.
I want to prevent the users from entering a CC# in the comments section of our application and give a warning to the user

All the Regexes  I searched on the internet works only if the string contains a credit card number("12345678910")

example

string comment ="Customer called in and gave his credit card number 12345678910.I will place an order for the customer"

In this case,I want to let the user know that this comment cannot be saved because it contains a credit card number

This is the sample code that I have and is not working

```
public class CreditCardValidator
    {
        public CreditCardValidator()
        {
            //These are the regex for all the avialble Credit  cards.http://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html

            this.Patterns = new string[] { "^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$", "^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$", "^3[47][0-9]{13}$", "^3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}$", "^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}$","^(?:2131|1800|35\\d{3})\\d{11}$" };
        }
        public string[] Patterns { get; set; }
        public  bool HasCreditCardNumber(string input)
        {
            foreach (var pattern in Patterns)
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline))
                {
                    return true;
                }                   
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: Build the regex, compare the input to it, and if there is a match raise an error. Where is the problem?

Comment: Which types of credit cards will you be taking into account?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_card_number You're going to have to have Regexes for each type of credit card.

Comment: Have you had problems with users putting credit card numbers in comments? If so, it sounds like a training/discipline issue and not something that should be fought through trying to detect credit card numbers in code.

Comment: @Share1er80 ,we deal with all the major credit cards.This is the sample code I have so far,but this doesnt seem to be working

Comment: @David Amo,I totally agree with you ,but I lost that battle to business

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `^` at the beginning and the `$` at the end of each regex pattern and it will work. These say "has to begin with" / "has to end with". And even with the multiline option it is still true for lines.

I guess these regex patterns where made to exactly match an input to a credit card number. But won't work for a in-text-search.

Comment: Thanks Robert for your suggestion.Helped me fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

I ended up making this change and seems to be working.THanks all for your feedback

//string comment = @"This is my credit card 4418831001112089.Please make an  order for me ";

```
public static bool HasCreditCardNumber(string input)
    {
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"\b4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?\b|\b5[1-5][0-9]{14}\b|\b3[47][0-9]{13}\b|\b3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}\b|\b6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}\b|\b(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11}\b");
        if (matches.Count > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }            
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the regex. Then when you lose focus on the box then raise an error (either via an alert (ugly) or by invalidating the form or showing a note saying this is invalid because...) and don't let the user submit the form. This isn't really something that C# can do automatically. You could wait until the click event to validate it.... but I would do it right away.

Answer (score 0):

Use the credit card match expression, but do a negative assertion on it.  This will trigger any client side validation and it should be plug and play.